# ActionScript 3 Repeated clicks slows down the program

Tags: actionscript-3

So I've got a number of frames, and in one frame I have a movieclip with the following code:
It adds a Shape to draw some biological cells that change colour when a particular movieclip called 'test' is pressed. 'morphogen1',... are other movieclips that can be dragged around.

```
cells = new Shape()
this.addChild(cells)
this.setChildIndex(cells,1)

function drawcell(xx,yy){
    if(logic(xx,yy)){col=0xFF4444}else{col=0xFFBBBB}
    with(cells.graphics){
    beginFill(col)
    drawCircle(xx,yy,5)
    endFill()
    }
}

function drawcells(){
    for(i=0;i<=15;i++){
        for(j=0;j<=10;j++){
            drawcell(i*22,j*14)
        }
    }
}

function dist(x1,y1,x2,y2){
    return Math.exp(-((x1-x2)*(x1-x2)+(y1-y2)*(y1-y2))/50000)
}

function logic(xx,yy){
    va = dist(xx,yy,morphogen1.x,morphogen1.y)
    vb = dist(xx,yy,morphogen2.x,morphogen2.y)
    vc = dist(xx,yy,morphogen3.x,morphogen3.y)
    if(ctrl==1){sa=(va>0.5)}else{sa=(va<vb)}
    return sa&&(vb>0.5)&&(vc>0.5)
}

test.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, swap)

function swap(e:MouseEvent){
    ctrl = 1-ctrl
    drawcells()
}
```

It works as intended, but the more 'test' is clicked, the more the program slows down; by 30 clicks the lag is very noticeable.

I am an amateur programmer - probably I've committed some major nono; is the event listener clogging the cpu? I've tried removing the Math.exp function with something much simpler, but same problem.

Comment: Try with hardware acceleration activated.

Comment: How do you do that? Is it some setting in Flash or in Windows?

Comment: I put an answer for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To activate hardware acceleration for your swf file, go to **File** > **Publish Settings...** or simply **CTRL** (win) / **Cmd** (mac) + **Shift** + **F12**, you will get this window and at the bottom you select a hardware acceleration :

[image: SWF Publish Settings]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I've experimented with it a bit more. The problem is not speed; even if you leave a lot of time between clicks, the next click still lags by a second or so.

Comment: I think that's a memory leak problem, In this case, you can try to clear your `cells.graphics` using `cells.graphics.clear()` before draw cells.

Comment: That worked! Your're a life-saver. Sorry I don't have enough reputation to vote up the answer!